# What is the mean of « is believed to »

Tags: phrase-meaning

I give an example.

Alex is believed to have been played in London.

Comment: It’s not grammatical.  Alex is believed to ***have*** been...   Once that is fixed the question becomes “Is Alex the name of a song (or a game)?” Or did Alex (a person) get *played*  (taken advantage of/swindled)

Comment: "Alex is believed to have been played in London" is a nested passive construction that obscures (1) the identity of the entity or entities that possess the specified belief and (2) the identity of the entity or entities that did the playing. Reframed as a fully elaborated idea, the sentence would be "X believe[s] that  Y played Alex in London," where X is the person, people, entity, or entities that that believe what follows in the sentence, and Y is the person, people, entity, or entities that played Alex in London.

Comment: @Alex123 - "Alex is believed to have been played in London." - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: By the way - en anglais, on n'utilise pas les guillemets français.

Comment: It is grammatical, although it is hard to see how such a sentence could arise in practice. One example is if Alex is a character in a play. The sentence could then mean "Some people suspect but don't know for sure that an actor or actors played the character of Alex in London in the past."

Comment: I will remember it tk’s 

Comment: Dad: Where were you? Alex: I was playing in London. Narrator: We accept Alex's statement that he was playing in London; Alex is believed to have been playing in London.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there are people who believe that "Alex" has been played in London (assuming that "Alex" is a play); this is a way to assert that there is ground to believe that this true, although a certain doubt remains.

Comment: It could also mean that the character of Alex was played. Or, in another sense, that Alex was the one who was **conned** in London. (To *play* someone is another way of saying that you fool or hoodwink someone.)